# NovaCode DocX can't replace the correct items in my word template

Tags: c#, ms-word, novacode-docx

I have created a generic function to generate doc files using the DocX library but it doesn't work with all items in my doc template.

It replaces just the first items and make the same txt in others ones. My doc parameters is set like this: `el0,el1,el3 .... el36`

```
public void GenerateFile (string template, List<string> data)
{
    try { 
        //if (File.Exists(template))
        //{
        DocX dDocument;

        dDocument = DocX.Load(template);

        for (int i = 1; i < data.Count(); i++)
        {
            var item = data[i];

            if (item == null)
            {
                item = " ";
            }

            var el = "el" + i;
            dDocument.ReplaceText(el.ToString(), item);
        }

        string time = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "" + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "" + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + "" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + "" + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() + "" + DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString();

        var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/temp/" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(template) + "_" + time + ".docx");

        dDocument.SaveAs(path);
        downloadFile(path);
        //}
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the concepte of my entries, i'm used Dictionary with key,value

```
public void GenerateFile(string template, Dictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        try {
            DocX dDocument;

            dDocument = DocX.Load(template);


            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                dDocument.ReplaceText("[["+item.Key+"]]", item.Value);

            }

            var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/temp/" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(template) + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssFFF") + ".doc");
            dDocument.SaveAs(path);
            downloadFile(path);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        }
```